# Output Audio via HDMI and Analog Out Simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

I need to output the system audio from a desktop to both the HDMI output (sending to the display that functions as the room speakers) and via the analog stereo output (to feed the reference input on a microphone array for Skype).

The only solution I've found so far for this is an [HDMI Audio De-Embedder](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-HDMI-Audio-De-Embedder-with-3D-Support.html), but I'd really like to avoid buying another piece of hardware, so I'm hoping there's a way to do this inside software.

**So: Is there any way to make Windows 7 output all audio over both HDMI and Analog outs, simultaneously?**

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent 100% on the drivers themselves.  Look in the audio control panel itself.  Also check the audio preferences specific to the application.  If it allows output to both devices, you'll probably find it within the control panel.  If the driver allows it, then yes.  It's not much of an answer, but there it is.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not natively supported by any of the applications we're using nor Windows itself.  I'm kind of hoping that somebody has written something that appears as a new hardware device to the system and then lets you send it to as many outputs as desired.

Comment: That is a great thought, about being a new hardware device, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Follow the steps in the accepted answer to the Microsoft Community question: [Is it possible to have speakers and HDMI play at the same time?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/is-it-possible-to-have-speakers-and-hdmi-play-at/4563a5f8-4be4-4463-b312-eff594a9ae49)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Virtual DJ Studio 2015 this allows me to use 3.55 mm audio out (integrated sound card) to my analog monitor speakers and the other HDMI out (from my video card) to my HDMI enabled TV, which has an audio out to that goes to my amplifier (audio in).